# ENOSPC error, but camera is working

Tags: python

I'm using a home  security system which seems to be working well, but when I type
python alarm.py in terminal, I get this error:

```py
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python alarm.py
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port            vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x5cf140 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alarm.py", line 27, in <module>
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

I have seen in another forum that a common  cause for this issue is that the camera is being used by a second application, but how can I find out which application(s) the camera is using? And could you tell me the steps to follow in terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I actually  found the reason for the ENOSPC error!
I'm also using a systemctl script to run the Python code at rpi startup, so with that script already running, I then type Python alarm.py in terminal,
which gives me the error message.

So I used `systemctl stop alarm.service`  and the error message disappeared, then I typed
 `systemctl start alarm.service` to start it again.
Why didn't I think of that ages ago?
Anyway, thank you